# Allow "suggested edits" to be less than 10 characters

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits, character-limit

Right now, a user making a suggested edit to a Q or A, must make at least 10 chars change, as there is a filter to that effect which seems to be active on all subsites.

The problem is that quite often a useful edit is less than this size. I hit 3 examples in the last 24 hours alone:

- A typo where the user typed "peace" but meant "piece"; the result made the final sentence meaningless and perhaps even misleading (to others who might think this was correct);
- An answer where an incorrect word was used (FreeBSD doesn't have "bind" mounts, the answer meant a "nullfs" mount on that OS);
- An answer which used an incorrect symbol that would prevent the answer working if tried as-stated.

In all these, the issue is the same - there may be useful edits/corrections that are under 10 chars.

If one is suggesting an edit to **someone else's** edit, there usually isn't any justification to add unnecessary extra text purely to get >=10 chars changed. It would be best practice to make the *least possible change*, even just 1-2 chars, out of respect for the user who made the post. I'm also having difficulty seeing how this limitation connects to a risk of misuse, such as spam or other problems.

Can we review whether this limitation is helping or hindering the site, and whether there is really any risk of issues or spam if those users who can suggest edits, could suggest edits < 10 chars?

If the conclusion is that it would help, could this change be made?

Comment: It's 6 characters, not 10 characters. But anyway, I do agree with you.